# NavigationDrawer : java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method Viewgroup.getPaddingLeft() on a null object reference

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I am implementing a navigation drawer in a base activity and using it in few other activities extending the base activity. i have made sure all the views are  defined in my xml. However, i get the error

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
'int android.view.ViewGroup.getPaddingLeft()' on a null object reference
```

The error is shown on the line `setContentView(layoutResId)` in the activity extending the base activity.

I am doing this

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

   }
```

`setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);` is before `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);`  as i am extending the base activity that does the work for navigation drawer.

I am sure all my layouts have proper ids that is needed for the drawer activity (the base activity). The code is below:

**drawer_layout.xml**

```
public class DemoNavActivity extends DrawerAppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    setContentView(R.layout.drawer_layout);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    }
}
```

**DrawerAppCompatActivity.java**

```
public class DrawerAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
public ListView mPreferenceList;
public ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

public CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

public CharSequence mTitle;

public String[] navMenuTitles;
public TypedArray navMenuIcons;

public ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
public NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

TextView user_name, user_email,btnLogin;
CircleImageView profileImage;
LinearLayout user_details, drawer;
FacebookUser user;
Gson gson;

public static SharedPreferences prefs;
public static SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    prefs = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = prefs.edit();

    gson = new Gson();

    user_name = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_name);
    user_email = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.user_email);
    btnLogin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    profileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.userProfileImage);
    user_details = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.user_details);
    drawer = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer);

    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FacebookLoginActivity.class));
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
        }
    });

    if (prefs.getString("user","").equals("")){
        user_details.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        btnLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }else{
        user_details.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        btnLogin.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        user = gson.fromJson(prefs.getString("user", ""), FacebookUser.class);

        Picasso.with(this).load(user.image).into(profileImage);
        user_name.setText(user.name);
        user_email.setText(user.email);
    }


    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    mPreferenceList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_preferences);

    ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = (ViewGroup.LayoutParams) drawer
            .getLayoutParams();
     params.width = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels * 4/5 ;
//        params.width = LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT;
    drawer.setLayoutParams(params);

//set adapter to listview
    mPreferenceList.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(
            R.color.bg_grey));

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();
    navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(
            R.array.prefrence_names);
    navMenuIcons = getResources().obtainTypedArray(
            R.array.preference_icons);

    for (int i = 0; i < navMenuTitles.length; i++) {
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[i], navMenuIcons
                .getResourceId(i, -1)));
    }

    navMenuIcons.recycle();

    adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems);
    mPreferenceList.setAdapter(adapter);
    mPreferenceList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_menu, R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name) {

        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
//                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        };

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
//                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        };
    };

    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.bhitta_menu, menu);
    return true;
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == android.R.id.home) {
        onBackPressed();
    }else if(id == R.id.action_preferences){
        mDrawerLayout.openDrawer(Gravity.LEFT);
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


private class SlideMenuClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                            long id) {
        displayView(position);
    }
}

private void displayView(int position) {
    switch (position){

        case 0:
            Toast.makeText(DrawerAppCompatActivity.this, "asdlkfjlsdf", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;

    }
}


}
```

This very code used to work before but now i am not able to rectify what's going wrong.

Please advise.

Comment: You should be calling `setContentView()` after the `super.onCreate()` call.

Comment: Doing that will give me another exception saying that the views are null. And i cannot call methods like setOnClicklistener on the views.

Comment: Because you're not calling `setContentView()` in `DrawerAppCompatActivity`. It makes no sense to try to setup `View`s in `DrawerAppCompatActivity` if you're not setting a layout there. Either call `setContentView()` in `DrawerAppCompatActivity`, or move the `View` setups to `DemoNavActivity`.